# What is the Solr/Lucene process to purge deleted documents in index?

Tags: solr, lucene

What is the process to purge index when you've got some deleted documents (after a delete by query) in index ?

I'm asking this question because I'm working on a project based on solr and I've noticed a strange behavior and I would like to have some informations about it.

My system got those features :

- My documents are indexed continuously (1000docs per second)
- A purge is done every couple of second with this query :

  ```
  <delete><query>timestamp_utc:[ * TO NOW-10MINUTES ]</query></delete>
  ```

So I got 600000 documents everytime visible in my index : 
10 Minutes * 60 = 600 seconds
and speed = 1000docs/s so  600 * 1000 = 600000

But the size of my index increase with the time. And I know that when you do a delete by query the documents are affected by a "delete" label or something like that in the index.

I've seen and tried the attribute "expungeDeletes=true", but I didn't notice a considerable change on my index size.

Any informations about the index purge process would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit**

I know that an optimize can to do this job but it's a long operation and I want to avoid that.

Comment: See previous related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053425/how-do-i-remove-logically-deleted-documents-from-a-solr-index

Comment: Unrelated to your qn: Do you really need Solr for this use case? If all you need is your doc IDs in the past 10 min, a technology like Redis may be better suited.

Comment: Yes, I need to you solr because it's for a internship work. But thanks you for this alternative, I would talk about that.

Comment: Thanks Paige for this advice. But optimizing is a very time consuming. Is there another way to speed up the purge of deleted docs. For exemple adjusting the merge Factor or the commit frequency ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new collection/core every 10 minutes, switch to it (plus the previous) and delete the oldest collection/core (later than 10 minutes).